# SQL Server 2012 restrict CmdExec to sysadmin server role

Tags: sql-server-2012, security

I'm trying to restricting `CmdExec` rights to sysadmin server role in SQL Server 2012. I've googled but just found some solution which they were for older version of SQL Server. Can you please help?

Comment: Do you mean `cmdexec` in the context of a SQL Agent job? Or `xp_cmdshell`which can be run from any old TSQL query?

Comment: @JohnM exactly, I mean `cmdexec` in the context of SQL Agent

Comment: @mhesabi - are you trying to make it so only members of the sysadmin role can *create* SQL Server Agent Job Steps that use `CmdExec` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to restrict this other than monitoring for it. I generally don't want sysadmins (or local server admins) running jobs. Where possible, I use proxy accounts with minimal required permissions. You can run the below to find what is lurking about now as proxies. If you are not using a proxy, the job will be running under the agent service account.

```
USE MSDB
GO
EXEC SP_ENUM_PROXY_FOR_SUBSYSTEM @subsystem_name = 'CmdExec'
GO
```